# Recieve text instead of speech from Direct Line Speech channel using Microsoft's BotFramework SDK

Tags: json, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, direct-line-botframework, mrtk

I sort-of followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmv4cPZuh5k&ab_channel=MicrosoftDeveloper, to create a bot with the QnA Maker for a HoloLens 2 project. However, the response back from the bot is an audio response, and I need the text response. The code below is the method called when a response is received:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes ActivityReceived events.
    /// Along with various info that can be found in an event, it also contains
    /// a "HasAudio" flag that can be used to signal audio is present/ready for processing
    /// </summar>
    private void DialogServiceConnector_ActivityReceived(object sender, ActivityReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Activity received:\r\n {e.Activity} ");

        if (e.HasAudio)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Audio received");
            var audio = e.Audio;

            // for sample purposes, just save the entire file and playback. (can improved with streaming)
            var buffer = new byte[800];
            uint bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = audio.Read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                byteStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
            }

            // Write a wav header on the final stream now that we know the full length
            if (byteStream.Length > 0)
            {
                WaveAudioData.WriteWavHeader(finalStream, false, 1, 16, 16000, (int)byteStream.Length);
                byteStream.WriteTo(finalStream);
                audioData = new WaveAudioData(finalStream.ToArray());

                ClearStream(byteStream);
                ClearStream(finalStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `ActivityRecievedEventArgs` contains an `Activity` that 'Gets the activity associated with the event as a serialized JSON object', but I don't know how to access the 'text' property.

```
    private void CreateDialogServiceConnector()
    {
        Debug.Log($"CreateDialogServiceConnector enter");

        if (dialogServiceConnector == null)
        {
            if (subscriptionKey == string.Empty || region == string.Empty)
            {
                Debug.Log($"One or more input fields weren't provided. Check the fields in the Canvas object or in the script source");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DialogServiceConfig creation failed");
            }

            // Creates an instance of a DialogServiceConfig with your bot connection ID, subscription key, and service region.
            // Replace in the editor on the Canvas object OR directly in the code, above in the member declarations

            //dialogServiceConfig = BotFrameworkConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region, botID);
            var botConfig = BotFrameworkConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
            botConfig.Language = "en-US";

            if (botConfig == null)
            {
                Debug.Log($"One or more input fields weren't provided. Check the fields in the Canvas object or in the script source");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DialogServiceConfig creation failed");
            }

            AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
            //dialogServiceConnector = new DialogServiceConnector(dialogServiceConfig, audioConfig);
            dialogServiceConnector = new DialogServiceConnector(botConfig, audioConfig);

            dialogServiceConnector.ActivityReceived += DialogServiceConnector_ActivityReceived;
            dialogServiceConnector.Canceled += DialogServiceConnector_Canceled;
            dialogServiceConnector.Recognized += DialogServiceConnector_Recognized;
        }

        //listenOnceButton.interactable = true;
        stateIndicatorString = "DialogServiceConnector created";

        ttsAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        Debug.Log($"CreateDialogServiceConnector exit");
    }
```

Comment: The sample already logs the activity. Have you checked your debug log? Could you provide the output of "Activity received:" in your question?

Comment: If you want to get a text response instead of an audio response, why are you using the Direct Line Speech channel instead of the standard Direct Line channel?

Comment: @JohnKim I actually have been getting an error message: Cancellation details: WebSocket upgrade failed: Bad request (400). Error details: Failed with HTTP 400 Bad Request. And have been unable to get the rest of it to run so far. Not sure why, because I've triple checked that I'm using the Bot ID listed in the video.

Comment: @AP01 I have both set up in Azure, but initially I chose Speech because I need to ask the question verbally, and figured it wouldn't be an issue getting text instead of speech from the response, but maybe that's incorrect.

Comment: @MaddyVan
Is that your full error? It should give you a more detailed error than HTTP 400.

Comment: @JohnKim In full it says:
Cancellation details: WebSocket upgrade failed: Bad request (400). Error details: Failed with HTTP 400 Bad Request
wss://eastus.convai.speech.microsoft.com/api/v3?botId=**&enableBotMessageStatus=true&language=en-us
d*bot ID* is not registered to the given subscription id. Please verify the provided subscription details and language information.

Comment: If you're 100% sure your bot's APP ID and PW are correct, check if your endpoint is also correct. Or perhaps the bot is not reading from the appsettings that you input the ID and PW at. You should put a breakpoint in your code and see exactly what the variables appear as during runtime.

Comment: @MaddyVan This error usually means that Azure is unable to find the application with the Id in your Azure subscription account. Essentially, it doesn't exist. You mentioned: `I'm using the Bot ID listed in the video`. I'm not sure why you're doing that, but ideally you should be creating unique values.

Comment: @AP01 Sorry, I meant I'm using the Bot ID found in the same location listed in the video, but it's my bot's unique ID. However, while going through [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/voice-assistants?tabs=jre&pivots=programming-language-csharp), it seems as though I shouldn't even need to put in the bot's app ID and just need the speech key. But then I get the following error: Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1002. Error details: The server returned status code '405' when status code '101' was expected.

Comment: @JohnKim In the video I followed, she didn't set up a PW, endpoint, or alter the appsettings. Just said we needed the Speech Service key, region, and the bot ID. Is that an outdated method/should I have it set up differently? I created a Web App Bot using the 'create a bot' button in Language Studio after deploying my Knowledge Base.

Comment: What happens when you use the "Test in Web Chat" menu option in the Bot resource in Azure?

Comment: @AP01 testing in web chat works. I also tried creating another bot and testing in web chat worked for that one, but throws the same error when I run my application in Unity.

Comment: Have you tried the Direct Line text channel? You can use more than one channel at a time, so you don't need to disable speech.